# How to get date difference for date column against current date in Laravel?

Tags: postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to add all loan_amort values where `schedule is <= 30` days when schedule is subtracted against the current date. How would I do that? Here is my sample code. I couldn't figure out the `whereRaw` part. Please help. Thank you.

```
$totalDues = Amortization::select('loan_type', \DB::raw('SUM(loan_amortization) as total_current'))
                            ->where('payment_status',0)
                            ->whereRaw('date_diff(schedule,now()) <= 30')
                            ->groupBy('loan_type')
                            ->orderBy('loan_type')
                            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with td  as
   ( select  generate_series( now(), now()+interval '35 day', '1 day')  schedule )
select date_part('day',schedule-now()) diff;
```

I guess for you that translates to

```
->whereRaw('date_part(''day'',schedule-now() <= 30')
```

Comment: Hi, after inserting, it returns syntax error, unexpected ''day'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: The portion  "select date_part('day',schedule-now()) diff " is valid. The parameter day is  a literal value for Postgres and as such nees single quotes (') around it.  The error then occurs my translating that into the ->whereRaw within your framework. It would seem that I've incorrectly escaped the single quotes within the overall string by doubling ('') them. I seem to not know how that is  done within your framework.